# How do I know the current tag of Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, hgrc

Now, I am getting vim source code by Mercurial (`hg`):

```
root@flyingfisher-virtual-machine:/work/ABC/VIM_HG# hg tags |more
tip                             5228:3f65dc9c8840
v7-4a-039                       5227:a08fa2919f2b
v7-4a-038                       5225:8f983df0299f
v7-4a-037                       5223:91d478da863e
v7-4a-036                       5221:9982ec574beb
v7-4a-035                       5218:4ceacc1b0054
v7-4a-034                       5216:947edb6335d1
v7-4a-033                       5214:fa024ce48542
v7-4a-032                       5212:2741b46e96bf
v7-4a-031                       5210:839ebe7c1b2f
```

then

```
root@flyingfisher-virtual-machine:/work/ABC/VIM_HG# hg update v7-4a-018
216 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
```

After several hours, how do I know which tag I was worked on?

Is there some Mercurial command tell the current tag information?

Comment: Note that you're not actually "working on a tag". A tag is a fixed position in the history, not something that you work on per se. Perhaps you want bookmarks?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Latest tag in ancestors, using log and templating

`hg log -r "." --template "{latesttag}\n"`

Answer (score 23):

If you're positive that you're on a tagged revision, just use:

```
hg id
```

This will show the revision hash and any tags (and the branch name, if it exists).

If the current revision does not have a tag and you want to find the closest tagged ancestor, you can instead use:

```
hg id -r 'ancestors(.) and tag()'
```

or the equivalent, but shorter:

```
hg id -r '::. and tag()'
```

Both work by finding the intersection of all ancestors and all tagged revisions.

You can also look at the output of `hg log -G` to find out where you are (the current node in the revision graph will be marked with an `'@'` instead of an `'o'`) and then locate the nearest tag.

Comment: revset must be `ancestorS(.) and tag()` and better, because AND also produce revset (not a single revision) `last(ancestors() and tag())`

Comment: Will fix the `ancestors()` typo, but the `last()` should be implicit in `hg id`.

Comment: In my environment, only hg id works. the other two always report error "abort: unknown revision XXX"

Comment: @harris - old Mercurial (without revsets)?